# The best method for get value from radio button

Tags: jquery, html

```
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter"> Butter

$("????").change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
})
```

How is the best method for get current checked value from two input with one name? If i click on radio Milk then this should show me "Milk" etc.
I can add class for this and showing current value, but this is the best method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this: **Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/VtcPB/1/

Good read: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

Also Like @Casper said for `group` use : `$('input[name ="group1"]')` **Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/VtcPB/2/

Or little more optimized http://jsfiddle.net/VtcPB/3/  using `this.value` instead of `$(this).val()`

Or Another with more accuracy **demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/VtcPB/4/

Hope this helps

**code**

```
$("input:radio[name=group1]").click(function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});​
```

**OR**

```
$('input[name ="group1"]').on('change',function(){
   alert(this.value);
})​
```

**OR**

```
$('input[type="radio"]').on('change',function(){
   alert($(this).val());
})​
```

**OR**

```
   <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
    <input type="radio" name="group1" value="Butter"> Butter

$('input[type="radio"]').change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
})
```

Comment: How about multiple groups of radiobuttons?

Comment: hiya @CasparKleijne can do this `$('input[name ="group1"]')` in that case, Thanks for comment though cheers bruv

Answer (score 5):

You can use name which also serves as group for multiple radio buttons. We can use type but it will bind event to all radio button on the page.

```
$('input[name=group1]').change(function(){
   alert($(this).val());
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach to radio type inputs:

```
$('input:radio[name=group1'].change(function()
{
    alert($(this).val());
}
```

Comment: yeh you are right. by the way i vote up you before i answered :). I think you missed it. haha.. @Tats_innit

Comment: lol `:)` here you go +1 for your effort as well :) see you around

Comment: @Tats_innit: thanks, i am thinking to delete my answer, but you vote up :). Now wat i do?

Comment: :) your answer is valid and its cool man, even though its repeat, I a respect your effort, doesn't matter keep my +1anyways, cheers!